# Parameter is not visible in function

Tags: bash, function, parameters, positional-parameter

I am writing a script, where I need to work with parameters.

Here is my foo.sh:

```
say_hello()
{
  if [ "$1" == "hello" ]
  then
    echo "hello"
  else
    echo "<$1>"
  fi
}

echo "$1"
say_hello
```

The output looks very strange for me:

```
hello
<>
```

Could you explain me why in function I can`t work with params? And how I could pass script params in function?

Comment: Parameters to function are different from parameters to shell.

Comment: @SeanBright you are completely right. Thanks. Add this comment as an answer and I will choose it.

Comment: OR `say_hello "$@"` to pass all the parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters you pass to functions in your shell are different from parameters passed to the shell itself.

For example, if `print_script_args` looks like this:

```
echo $1
echo $2
```

then `./print_script_args hello world` will print this:

```
hello
world
```

and if `print_function_args` looks like this:

```
foo() {
    echo $1
    echo $2
}

foo bye world
```

then `./print_function_args hello planet` will print this:

```
bye
world
```

— the parameters to the script do nothing, because what's printed is the parameters passed to the shell function, namely `bye world`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `say_hello` function with an input parameter.

Within `say_hello`, `$1` refers to the first argument that was passed to that function. You are calling it without any arguments though, like this:

```
say_hello
```

What you want is pass `$1` (from the main script context) as a parameter to the `say_hello` function, like this:

```
say_hello $1
```

In the script, `$1` refers to the first argument passed to the script when it was run from the command-line. In the function `say_hello`, `$1` refers to the first argument that was passed to the function when it was called from the script.